# How to add Strings through streams in Java

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have validating a JSON request using the everit json dependency. If there are multiple errors, then it'll return a validationException which will contain a list of the validation exceptions.
I can print out the validations using the following code:

```
e.getCausingExceptions().stream()
                .map(ValidationException::getMessage)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But I would like to add each of the validations to a string but I'm not sure how to do it as I'm new to Java 8

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
String errs = e.getCausingExceptions().stream()
               .map(ValidationException::getMessage)
               .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're validating a JSON file against JSON Schema..

```
 List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
 try {
     Schema schemaValidator = SchemaLoader.load(jsonSchema);
     schemaValidator.validate(jsonObject);
 }catch(ValidationException e) {
     e.getCausingExceptions().stream().map(ValidationException::getMessage).forEach(err -> {
         errorList.add(err);
     });
 }
```